# evaluation an angular expression within quotes in html

Tags: html, angular

I came across a scenario where I had to evaluate an angular expression within quotes like below

```
<a href="mailto:{{account["email"]}}"
```

But the above doesn't properly evaluate content in child quotes(repEmail). 
**How do I resolve this?**

Comment: `{{ account['email'] }}`? Otherwise you're ending the attribute value. Or just `account.email`.

Comment: Try to use single quotes around `'email'` word

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 <a href="mailto:{{account['email']}}"
```

or

```
 <a href="mailto:{{account.email}}"
```

or

```
 <a ng-attr-href="mailto:{{account['email']}}"
```

or

```
 <a ng-attr-href="mailto:{{account.email}}"
```